# PHP : Fetch byte array from C# Web API

Tags: php, arrays, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to fetch byte array from C# Web API. C# client can perfectly fetch byte array but it comes in PHP then it shows random string. This string looks like encoded.

I have tried the same API with POSTMAN also. Postman also provided same encoded string. How can I fetch byte array from C# web API in PHP?

I am using HTTP request with content-type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded. This API suppose to give byte array for the following the text,

Required Byte array of content: This is demo file.
Actual response: VGhpcyBpcyBkZW1vIGZpbGUuCg==

Comment: Please share more details. If you are running an API over HTTP, there is no such thing as a "byte array" when this request is handled in PHP

Comment: I am sending http request with content-type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Using get method trying to fetch byte array. This byte array is shown encode string as follows,
VGhpcyBpcyBkZW1vIGZpbGUuCg==

Comment: Please add all explanation to the question itself, not to the comment section

Comment: Use `base64_decode` on the returned data.

Answer (score 0):

Byte values ​​come from webapi as strings. You need to convert this value to `base64` type.

```
string str = yourbytestring;
byte[] cnvbyte = Convert.FromBase64String(str.ToString());
```